# Product/Multiplication NSMutableArray Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an NSMutableArray and I need to make the product of all the numbers inside it.
I just can't understand how to do.
PS. I'm quite new with objective-c so be as clear as possible.
Thank's

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. Apart from that, this is not very Objective-C specific either. You initialize the result to 1, then you loop over the array and multiply the result by the next element in the array.

Comment: And it should be noted that it's kind of dangerous to be programming in Objective-C without knowing how to program in C or Java first.  You will pick up all sorts of bad habits and misconceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can also do like this..

```
int result=1;
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
result*=[[array objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
}
NSLog(@"%d     ",result);
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that, while the use of NSExpression or KVC stuff is fine, the above is both more efficient and easier for the novice to understand.  The one "trick" is that the numbers will be stored as NSNumber (or perhaps NSString) values, so you need to apply `integerValue` to get an NSInteger you can manipulate in an arithmetic expression.  The loop itself is something that every programmer should know as second nature.

Answer (score 0):

H2CO3 is right. For the sake of completeness try

```
NSNumber * sum = [numArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

where numArray is your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on NSExpression class it's very powerfull and you can customize it to your requirements. It's also support many build in functions, for example:

```
NSArray *nums = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5];
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:nums]]];
id result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're working with `int` values...

```
int sum = 1;
for (NSNumber *num in someArray) {
    sum *= [num intValue];
}
NSLog(@"%d", sum);
```

`int` and `intValue` can easily be replaced with `double` and `doubleValue` or whatever is appropriate for what you need.  `someArray` is the name of the array of values.

---

If, however... the question is poorly worded and we've all misunderstood, and you need a new array whose indices contain the product of the values of the objects at the same indices in two other arrays, then you're looking for something more like this:

```
NSMutableArray *productArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=0; i<[arr1 count]; ++i) {
    int product = [[arr1 objectAtIndex:i] intValue] * [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]
        intValue];
    [productArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: product]];
}
```