# How to get Product/Multiple array of intergers in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, operands, nsexpression

i having a scenario get product/multiply of array integers. 
were i'm to able for sum using below line of code

```
NSNumber* sum = [intarr valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
```

Using NSExpression also able to get sum but not getting product/Multiply

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:intarr]]];  
id result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

can anyone suggest me how to get product/multiply of self Array of integer

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719294/product-multiplication-nsmutablearray-values

Comment: im looking alternate way.instead for loop

Answer (score 0):

As per Greg's answer If you don't want to use loop then use:

```
NSArray *nums = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5];
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:nums]]];
id result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

Comment: im trying to get Product/Multiplication Not sum

Comment: @MohnishVardhan You could use `multiply:by:` instead of `sum:`, but I guess (haven't tested) that this only works with 2 variables. Anyway, you can try. Here is an example of it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29517108/4370893